# Javascript Error: DOM Exception 8 using jQuery and an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, splice

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM
>   Exception 8

Here is my code (please suggest anything to make it more efficient / cleaner):

Basically this is a button thats adding it's ID to an array called 'keywords':

```
$('.add').live('click', function() {
    if($(this).text() == "+Add") {
        console.log("add triggered");
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#999d92'}, 300);
        $(this).html("-Rem").fadeIn('fast'); 
        keywords.push($(this).attr("id"));
        $("#response").append(keywords); 

    }
    else {
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#cc6633'}, 300);
        $(this).html("+Add").fadeIn('fast'); 
        var index = keywords.indexOf($(this).attr("id"));
        keywords.splice(index, index+1);
        $("#response").append(keywords); 
    }

});
```

What I want to happen is when "+ADD" is pushed the id attribute is added to the array, and when -REM is pushed then remove that id from the keywords.

Any advice would really be a help. When I just append $(this).attr("id") to the response div it does print correctly. I also tried surrounding it with a "String()" function (perhaps it was a reference to the resource and not the actual string?)

Thanks a head of time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
keywords.splice(index, index+1);
```

The second argument to `splice` is a number of items to remove, so that should probably be just `1`.

```
$("#response").append(keywords);
```

But `keywords` is an array of strings? jQuery documents no such interface for `append`.

Do you want something like:?

```
$("#response").text(keywords.join(', '));
```

Comment: Excellent thank you! :) I still had append in there instead of text